# Create one, single public site without enabling this on the whole tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, anonymous-authentication

We would like to restrict access to our Sharepoint sites to only authenticated users (internal and external), an put one, single page with some information for those who are really lost (looking for contact, lost pw etc). 
Is this possible without enabling anyonymous access on the tenant? I know that enabling this only gives the option for SharePoint admins to open a site to the public, and will not open by default (not sure, what will happen to Public groups though), but still, this site should be the exception and not the standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option to create a public site had been deprecated a long time ago and I think it is now completely removed from SharePoint Online / Office 365. If you want to display information to anonymous visitors you would have to host it somewhere else.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3027254/sharepoint-online-public-websites-to-be-discontinued

Comment: "Beginning May 1, 2017, anonymous access for existing sites will no longer be available. If customers need more time to move their public website, they have a one-time postponement option for up to one year (March 31, 2018). Customers must select the postpone option by May 1, 2017."
This is strange, I can still enable anonymous access.

Comment: Are you sure? It's not just for sharing documents or some other scenario? Because you can share document and folders anonymously, but not sites (and I assume not pages). https://support.office.com/en-us/article/external-sharing-overview-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85

Comment: Hm, yes, looks indeed sharing. "Allow sharing to authenticated external users and using anonymous access links " So, I could, in theory make a site page, share the link to that page, anyone with the link can access it. I didn't try this yet though.